# Using custom named controllers with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

Hi I'm working on a application that uses a admin environment and a user environment. To make my code and controllers more readable I would like to use some kind of a prefix for my admin and user controllers. Or maybe use a different directory for the admin en user controllers. Without using the exact name in the url to call the controllers.

Does anybody know if there is a way to do this or a work around for my idea.
For example I would like to use: user.[controllername].php or user_[controllername].php

EDIT:

So when I use routes to separate the user controllers from the admin controllers, it brakes my template resolver.

For instance lets say the url is: http://myapplication.com/user/profile in normal cases this would call the user controller and the function profile. My template resolver looks for the folder user and checks if there is a level1.tpl file.
Lets say we want to edit this profile the url would be: http://myapplication.com/user/profile/edit/1 now it would search in the folder user for a level2.tpl file and would call the function edit with id 1.

The problem with the routes is that it prepends something to the url witch I don't want because then it searches in the wrong folder for instance when we use admin/dashboard it will look in the folder admin instead of the folder dashboard.

[image]

So basically what I only need is only to tell the application to use a different directory where the controllers are located or a different filename base on what kind of user is logged in.

Thanks in advance, for sharing you knowledge.

Comment: What about just using routes? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: You can also create a folder to leave your `admin` controllers physically separated from the `user` ones, if you prefer. When you access your URL e.g. `example.com/admin/dashboard` (saying you removed `index.php`), Codeigniter will look for the `Dashboard` controller into the folder named `admin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in many ways.

**1.** Create two file in application/core named "Admin_Controller.php" and "User_Controller.php" with following class signature,

```
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller
{    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and

```
class User_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

In these classes you can do use your PHP logic to do whatever you wants, just simply extends your Controllers to Admin_Controller or User_Controller.
eg: `class Home extends User_Controller {}` or `class Dashboard extends Admin_Controller {}`

**2.** You can also simply do that with routes.php

eg:

```
// for admin
$route['admin/(.+)'] = 'admin_$1';

// for frontend
$route['(.+)'] = 'user_$1';
```

I hope this might give you some idea.

Comment: Is it also possible to not prepend anything extra to the url? 
I am also using custom directories for my templates incombination with smarty that works just fines but it also builds my templates based on the url structure so when I append something to the url the application looks in the wrong folders for the template files.

Comment: ok then you need to map every possible request to its respective controller. eg: `/home` would load `Home controller`, `/dashboard` would load `Dashboard controller` etc. For that, simply create a new file in application/core with file `MY_Controller.php` with signature `MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {}` in this class simply use a method `public function _remap() {}` where you can use switch case for appropriate class call. Besides this you can also do that in routes file as well.